# error log for changing background image script, Google Chrome

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-chrome, typeerror

I'm having trouble getting my background-changing script to work in Google Chrome. I'm developing a custom WordPress theme, I've used the following jQuery, and it doesn't seem to do anything except for add my first class in. When I inspect element and look at the source, it's throwing the error "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'slice' of undefined", with a little red number that keeps going up next to it. Obviously it's running the code and that's what the red number keeps going up every two seconds for. Any ideas why this isn't working?

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
jQuery(".background").addClass("foo image-1 bar");

setInterval(function() {
  jQuery("body").toggleClass(function(index, className) {
    var s = className.split("image-")[1];
     var n = s.slice(0, 1);
    return "image-" + n + " image-" + (n > 3 ? 1 : ++n);
  });
}, 2000); });
```

Also, this code works fine in JSFiddle. So I know the code is good.

Comment: The red number means the that error happened how ever many times the number says in a row. So instead of spamming the console with the same error over and over, it just shows the amount of times it happened

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You add the `foo image-1 bar` classes to the elements with `.background`, but then do a `toggleClass` on `body`.  You should change one or the other to match.  Right now, it's failing because there are no classes on `body`

Here is a working fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/zhft5958/1/

Comment: Wow I feel stupid...thank you very much. Sometimes it's the little things going wrong!